# python udf in hive

Tags: java, python, sql, hadoop, hive

I want to write hive udf in python to parse name column (using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nameparser) and put the parsed values in different columns of table(title,first,middle,last,suffix,nickname).

I am new to python ,I wrote python code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from nameparser import HumanName
name = HumanName(name)
return name.title
```

And in hive am doing like this

```
add file title.py;
SELECT TRANSFORM (name) using 'title.py' AS (title STRING) from emp2;
```

but am getting org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException.

Answer (score 0):

In the select statement using clause, you need to specify '**python** title.py' instead of title.py.

```
add file title.py;
SELECT TRANSFORM (name) using 'python title.py' AS (title STRING) from emp2;
```